# How can I get an elevation profile of a driving route

Tags: usa, driving

Looking for website that will create an elevation profile at, say 100m horizontal intervals, of a US driving route on google maps that's on the order of 1000 miles.

Comment: Like a topographic map?

Comment: related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9891/route-planner-with-heights-for-bikes

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196111/draw-route-and-elevation-profile

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: A topographic map contains this data, but a "profile" has it displayed in a very different way.  See the example in my previous comment.

Comment: I've seen elevation profiles on Google Maps accompanied by cycling directions, but never for driving.

Answer (score 1):

Try a cycling route planner like [Ride With GPS](https://ridewithgps.com/help/planning)

Answer (score 1):

The USGS has an app that lets you overlay on a US map. It also let's you see an elevation profile along a multi-point line. But it does not let you select a specific roadway. https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/advanced-viewer/